# Powershell html Fetch / Scrape class

Tags: powershell, scrape, powershell-3.0

I am trying to fetch from [this site](http://www.in.com/tv/channel/set-max-51.html). I am trying to fetch the first show in the list and output it to text.

So far I tried this, but not able get success. any feedback would be helpful.

```
$hsg = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.in.com/tv/channel/set-max-51.html
$hsg | gm -MemberType Property
##$hsg.Links
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I am not able to see the class in the list so I can fetch it `$hsg.Links | select class | sort class -Unique`

Answer (score 1):

This works for PowerShell v2. Invoke-WebRequest is v3, which I do not have on this machine.

```
$hsg = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$hsg.Navigate("http://www.in.com/tv/channel/set-max-51.html")

$Links = @($hsg.document.getElementsByTagName("a"))
$Links | fl href
```

This gets all links, but return the first is trivial once you know how to get the links in the first place.

There are 687 links on that page right now, just interesting as its a slow scrape.

Comment: Thanks, but It didn't work with version 3. I get this error `Cannot find an overload for "getElementsByTagName" and the argument count: "1".`